# SUBSTRING_INDEX this or that

Tags: mysql

How would I do the following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(log, 'Basic/urn:' OR 'Basic/urh:', -1)
```

In other words, I want to split on two different strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you just want this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(log,
                       (CASE WHEN log like '%Basic/urn:%' THEN 'Basic/urn:' ELSE 'Basic/urh:',
                       -1)
```